# Bash script double quote escaping

Tags: bash, escaping

I'm trying to run a command in a bash script using a variable as a parameter, but I am failing to correctly escape the quotes.
This is what I have have:

```
vsnames=$(comm -13 --nocheck-order $cur_ha_stat_report $old_ha_stat_report | awk -F\| '{print $1}' | tr '\r\n' ' ')
create event type=0xfff00033 text="$vsnames" mh=$dev_mh &
```

Where vsnames is a string with words separated by spaces.
When I run the script, this is what I get:

```
+ vsnames='VS1 VS2 '
+ create event type=0xfff00033 'text=VS1 VS2 ' mh=xxx
```

How to I put the $vsnames variable between quotes?
I have tried using `\"` but it didn't work, bash just added a bunch of unwanted single-quotes.
Any tips?
The command I actually need is:
`create event type=0xfff00033 text="VS1 VS2 " mh=xxx`

Comment: The single quotes are auto added by bash after bash expands your expansions so that they meet your intentions. Usually you don't need to worry about them. Is there any unexpected results after execution?

Comment: Yes, because if the double-quotes are missing, only the first one - "VS1" in the example - would be defined as the "text" parameter.

Comment: @mafagafo : Your question is not clear to me. Would you like the _create_ parameter be `text="VS1 " "VS2 "`? Please specify precisly, what arguments the command `create` is supposed to see.

Comment: @user1934428, I would like that parameter to be `text="VS1 VS2 "`
The complete command should be:
`create event type=0xfff00033 text="VS1 VS2 " mh=xxx`

Comment: Put this into your question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

With your variable `vsnames` being set to the 8-character-string `VS1 VS2`  (as we can see from the trace), doing a

```
create event type=0xfff00033 text=\""$vsnames"\" mh=xxx
```

would set the argv[2] of the `create` command to

```
text="VS1 VS2 "
```

Explanation: I have enclosed `$vsnames` into single quotes, to tell bash that we don't want to do word splitting here. Then I wrapped this between literal `\"` quotes, because you want `create` to see these quotes.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but the whole parameter was encapsulated in singue-quotes:
`create event type=0xfff00033 'text="VS1 VS2 "' mh=`
That is not too bad, but the attribute `text` was defined as `"VS1 VS2 "` instead of `VS1 VS2 `. Any way to get around that?

Comment: Are you sure that  _create_ wants to see single quotes around this argument? This woudl be odd, but trivial to do, if you really want it. Just wrap it between `\'`.

Comment: No, it doesn't want single quotes, only double quotes for attribute definition (text)

Comment: @mafagoto : Well, than this is exactly what I specified in my answer. Actually, with this information you can now place explicitly the quotes wherever you want them. Whenever you invoke an program from your script, imagine that this is a C program and think of what exactly should be stored in the `argc` vector for this program. With this picture, it is usually easy to write the parameters in a correct way.

Comment: So if I wanted to remove the double quotes, I should use:
`text=\"$vsnames\"` ?

Comment: `\"` explicitly supplies double quotes. As you said in your question, the variable `vsnames` does not contain any double quote, so why do you want to remove them? But you want to avoid word splitting. Your suggestion would make 3 parameters out of it: The first being `text="VS1`,  the second `VS2` and the third just a single `"`.  This does not make sense!

Comment: @mafagafo: In your response to my comment, you said that the parameter passed to the program should be `text="VS1 VS2 "` (which is 15 characters, if I don't miscount them), and this is what I described in my answer. If you want something different, you have to describe exactly what you want. Currently, I find it just confusing.

Comment: Let me try to make it clearer. If I wanted to run this command from CLI, i would type:
`create event type=0xfff00033 text="VS1 VS2 " mh=xxx`
That is what I want the script to do. The variable `vsnames` contains the text `VS1 VS2 `, but it could change.

Comment: I see. `create` should not see any quotes at all, neither double nor single. You need to say this in the question! The paramter would then be `text="$vsnames"` or `"text=$vsnames"`, depending on what you find easier to read.

Comment: `create` needs to see the double quotes after `text=`, as in `text="NS1 NS2 "`. That is in my initial question.

Comment: @mafagafo: .. and this is exactly what my answer provides. So, what are we discussing here?

Comment: your answer provided something akin to `text=""NS1 NS2 ""`, meaning that the double quotes ended up being part of the `text` parameter. I can see how confusing it is when I write it, but the problem is that the event I am creating ends up looking like this: `Issue found on instances "NS1, NS2 "`, when I wanted `Issue found on instances NS1, NS2 `

Comment: @mfagafo : You really need to make up your mind, on what you want: In the last sentence, it means that `create` does **not** want to see the quotes! How can we provide a suitable solution, when you say something different all the time. BTW, I did **not** say to create `text=""NS1 NS2 ""`. I suggested to write in the code `text=\""$vsnames"\"` which passes the string `text="NS1 NS2 "` to the application - since this is what you had asked at that time.

Comment: I don't want to take more of your time. Thanks for your help, I will keep that solution as it is. Cheers!